# No suitable Driver error

Tags: java, mysql

```
public void connect()
{
    try
    {
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
      String url = "jdbc:msql://23.249.225.135:3306/"; 
      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"s****d","1*****-");  
      System.out.println("DB works");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      System.err.println("Got an exception! "); 
      System.err.println(e.getMessage()); 
    } 
}
```

I have the JDBC driver in the /lib folder in my class path.
Keep getting:

```
No suitable driver found for jdbc:msql://23.249.225.135:3306/
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The version of your mysql database doesn't support the version of your driver or vice-versa. Look for the compatibility matrix http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-versions.html

Comment: You've misspelled `mysql` in the url is `msql`

Comment: @Titus respect for you :)

Comment: I think my answer does not matter anymore. This little misspelling catched by Titus is probably the right answer. @Titus. You should add your catch as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've misspelled `mysql` in the url is `msql`.

Comment: The small things... Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

The version of your mysql database doesn't support the version of your driver or vice-versa.

Look for the compatibility matrix here: [Chapter 2 Connector/J Versions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-versions.html)

[image]